# How to rearrange table in pandas in a format suitable for analysis in R?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, reshape

In pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'row1':['a','b','a','a','b','b','a','b','b','a'], 'row2':['x','x','y','y','y','x','x','y','x','y'],'col':[1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2],'val':[34,25,22,53,33,19,42,38,33,61]})

p = pd.pivot_table(df,values='val',rows=['row1','row2'],cols='col')

col         1   2
row1 row2        
a    x     34  42
     y     22  57
b    x     26  25
     y     38  33
```

Is it possible to reshape the pivot table in a data frame suitable for analysis in R?, something of the type:

```
  row1 row2 col val
    a   x   1   34
    a   y   1   22
    a   x   2   42
    a   y   2   57      
    b   x   1   26  
    b   y   1   38
    b   x   2   25
    b   y   2   33
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> pd.melt(p.reset_index(), id_vars=['row1', 'row2'],
            var_name='col', value_name='val')
  row1 row2  col  val
0    a    x    1   34
1    a    y    1   22
2    b    x    1   26
3    b    y    1   38
4    a    x    2   42
5    a    y    2   57
6    b    x    2   25
7    b    y    2   33
```

Which resets the index, making `row1` and `row2` columns:

```
>>> p.reset_index()
col row1 row2   1   2
0      a    x  34  42
1      a    y  22  57
2      b    x  26  25
3      b    y  38  33
```

And then `pd.melt` melts in all columns except `row1` and `row2` (`id_vars` parameter) into one column named `val` (`value_name` parameter) and keeps the information to which column they belonged in the column named `col` (`var_name` parameter).

Comment: Ah ha! I knew you'd eventually warm up to `melt`. Pun (sort of) intended :/

Comment: @PhillipCloud :D I use it. It's just that I hesitate to use it on SO since I don't want to melt the OP's brain :P But in this case it was really obvious... It should have been named unpivot :-/

Comment: Incidentally, we had a discussion about that over at pandas' github ([issue #4150](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/4150)). I agree with you, but `melt` is taken from R (specifically, the `reshape2` package by Hadley Wickham) and it has been in `pandas` for awhile I believe, so we decided to stick with it. `pivot` in R is called `dcast` (`data.frame` `cast`).

Comment: @PhillipCloud I think we should *add* unpivot as a melt alias (or vice versa). Then everyone's a winner. ... It seems strange to use melt but not (d)cast terminology from R.

Comment: @AndyHayden I wholeheartedly agree :)

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
In [11]: p.stack()
Out[11]: 
row1  row2  col
a     x     1      34
            2      42
      y     1      22
            2      57
b     x     1      26
            2      25
      y     1      38
            2      33
dtype: int64
```

This doesn't give a name attribute, so you have to set it as you [reset the index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
In [12]: df = p.stack().reset_index(name='val')

In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
  row1 row2  col  val
0    a    x    1   34
1    a    x    2   42
2    a    y    1   22
3    a    y    2   57
4    b    x    1   26
5    b    x    2   25
6    b    y    1   38
7    b    y    2   33
```

Comment: Just throwing this out there, but if this is faster than `melt` it might be worth implementing `melt` in terms of this.

Comment: @PhillipCloud As things get big, I'm not sure it's much faster... a little surprising how *vast* majority of time is spent doing the reset_index.