# Columns to row in python

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.4, transpose

Do we have sas equivalent of proc transpose. i have the following variables

```
 a b c d e f g
 1 3 4 5 3 2 2
 2 3 3 3 2 4 2
```

i want to transpose, across columns a and b , dummy out put below:

```
 a b tranposed_columns transposed_value
 1 3 c                 4
 1 3 d                 5
 1 3 e                 3
 1 3 f                 2
 1 3 g                 2
 2 3 c                 3
 2 3 d                 3
 2 3 e                 2
 2 3 f                 4
 2 3 g                 2
```

How can i do this in python, in sas i would have written

```
 proc transpose data=Dummy_data 
 out=ouput_data (rename=(col1=transposed_value _name_=tranposed_columns));
 by a b;
 run;
```

i tried dummy_data.T , but it tranposes all the data, also tried hands with pivot data, but its not repeating the rows.

```
dummy_data.pivot_table(index=['a','b'],values=['c','d','e','f','g'], aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
```

Comment: @unutbu: right, I missed this was about Pandas; the question title and first paragraph led me to the canonical duplicate.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18551342/190597

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pd.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) to coalesce columns into a single column. Use the `id_vars` parameter to "protect" certain columns from participating in the melt:

```
In [11]: pd.melt(df, id_vars=['a','b'], var_name='transposed_columns', value_name='transposed_value')
Out[11]: 
   a  b transposed_columns  transposed_value
0  1  3                  c                 4
1  2  3                  c                 3
2  1  3                  d                 5
3  2  3                  d                 3
4  1  3                  e                 3
5  2  3                  e                 2
6  1  3                  f                 2
7  2  3                  f                 4
8  1  3                  g                 2
9  2  3                  g                 2
```

Comment: thanks a lot for de-duplicating it . also this works perfectly fine. simple and elegant solution.